# pretrained object detection model with more classes than COCO

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I need to have a detector that can detect many different object. For that, the 90 classes of COCO are not enough because I would like to be able to see more.
I have seen that imagenet for instance has many more classes, however I couldn't find a model trained to detect imagenet classes.
I am programming on python and I want to avoid retraining a Network to detect more classes myself.
I have looked on pytorch vision and couple of other repositories but I didn't find anything.

EDIT: I have found a good one now, LVIS dataset has 1200 classes for detections and is using the images from coco (they relabelled them). There is good model for it with detectron2 from facebookai. https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/master/MODEL_ZOO.md
I think it's only avaliable for a cuda environnement though (I have no GPU :( )

Answer (score 2):

ImageNet unfortunately is not labelled for that purpose.
Off the shelf, you can try and use the [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). There are models trained on the OpenImages dataset which has 600 classes.

You can use them straight away for inference or if you wish, retrain them.

Comment: Thank you. I have also found another one that from detectron2 on LVIS dataset. (edited my post)

Answer (score 1):

Check https://keras.io/api/applications/ for more models/datasets

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np

model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Alex Rancea, but if I am not wrong, this is a classification model, what I need is one for object detection (ie I want one that draws bounding boxes, not that classifies images)

Comment: My fault. You can use Yolov3 https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/ and go to pretrained models(darknet53). Use the steps shown there.

Comment: hmm thank you, although it's not exactly what I am looking for.
first because I am working on windows so this version is a bit annoying to use, 2nd because I would like something that can be easier integrated into a python script and last because I need something legal and free to use, preferably also for commercial usage and this one seems quite suspicious
But I appreciate your help